# How do I delete cells based on a certain number of values?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large amount of data with some cells having a mixture of numbers, full stops and underscores. However, I want to make a macro that will delete cells that contains numbers etc, so that the only cells left contain letters from the alphabet. Below is the current code I have but it doesn't work properly. How do I fix it?

```
    Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim Lrow As Long


strSearch = "."
strSearch = "0"
strSearch = "1"
strSearch = "2"
strSearch = "3"
strSearch = "4"
strSearch = "5"
strSearch = "6"
strSearch = "7"
strSearch = "8"
strSearch = "9"
strSearch = "."


Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows
    With .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)
      .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
      .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

I also have this bit of code which doesn't work properly. Which one of the two should I use and how do I fix them? Also, which one should I use?

```
    Sub Test()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "3", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "4", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "5", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "6", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "7", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "8", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "9", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, "0", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each cell In Selection
If InStr(1, cell, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need am ***array*** for `strSearch`

Comment: Here's a good question that covers searching for alphabetical characters only (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633517/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-letters). This will almost surely simplify your code if you're willing to refactor.

Comment: Gary- Sorry, I am very in experienced with this, but I did hear array get mentioned alot. Where and how will I incorporate it?

Comment: Joe- I see it highlights it, but how would I remove cells that do not fit the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim strSearch As Variant

    strSearch = Array("*.*", "*0*", "*1*", "*2*", "*3*", "*4*", "*5*", "*6*", "*7*", "*8*", "*9*", "*_*")
    With Sheets("Sheet01")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: too vague a sentence... be more descriptive about what's not working in detail

Comment: I ran the macro, but nothing happened. I didn't get any error messages though.

Comment: I tested it with column A cells contents like "1abcd", "abcd1", "abcd.", "abcd_", "abc_d", "ab.cd", ... and they all got deleted.

Comment: also check the sheet name: I changed it to "Sheet01" not to conflict with other sheet of mine in my test workbook

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are hoping to accomplish with this macro. The below macro would satisfy what you are looking for:

```
Sub CleanNumerics()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim args() As Variant

' Load your arguments into an array to allow looping
args() = Array(".", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "_")

' Load your selection into a range variable
Set r = Selection

' By stepping backwards we wont skip cells as we delete rows.
For i = r.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    ' Loop through the number of arguments in our array.
    For j = 0 To UBound(args())
        ' If one of the noted characters is in the cell, the row
        ' is deleted and the loop exits.
        If InStr(1, r.Cells(i), args(j)) > 0 Then
            r.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

The problem with this approach is that you are deleting an entire row which could lead to issues depending on your application. Additionally, if you are doing this with a large dataset it could take a long time. You could use arrays to overcome this, but these can get complicated.

Doing it with an array would look something like this:

```
Sub ArrayWithoutNumbers()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim m As Long

Dim args() As Variant

Dim array_1() As Variant
Dim array_2() As Variant

Dim flag As Boolean

' Load your arguments into an array to allow looping
args() = Array(".", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "_")

' Load your selection into a range variable
On Error GoTo Err
array_1() = Selection.Value
On Error GoTo 0

' First determine if a two dimensional array has created. If so, loop through rows
' and columns. If not, go to the other loop.
If UBound(array_1, 2) > 1 Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(array_1, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(array_1, 2)
            flag = False
            For k = 0 To UBound(args())
                If InStr(1, array_1(i, j), args(k)) > 0 Then
                    flag = True ' Sets a flag so that the item is not added.
                    Exit For    ' Exit the loop
                End If
            Next

            ' If the flag hasn't been raised, resize the array and add the item.
            If flag = False Then
                m = m + 1
                ReDim Preserve array_2(1 To m)
                array_2(m) = array_1(i, j)
            End If
        Next
    Next

' Loops through only the rows of the array.

ElseIf UBound(array_1, 2) = 1 Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(array_1, 1)
        For k = 0 To UBound(args())
            If InStr(1, array_1(i), args(k)) > 0 Then
                flag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If flag = False Then
            m = m + 1
            ReDim Preserve array_2(1 To m)
            array_2(m) = array_1(i)
        End If
    Next
End If

' Adds a worksheet to output to. You can adjust this as needed.

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(array_2, 1), 1).Value = array_2()

Exit Sub

Err:

End Sub
```

The benefit to this is that you can clean up multiple rows and columns at once, and spit it back out.

Comment: Oh my gosh, this is one that finally works! Thank you! It takes a while, but I don't mind because it actually works!! :D

Comment: Not a problem! Depending on what you are doing, any loop can take a while, especially as you select larger ranges. Something to keep in mind though is that loading your values into memory (like I did with the arrays) is faster than trying to edit the worksheet since editing the worksheet has additional events attached to it.