# Export only text from the string, VBA

Tags: excel, string, vba

I have strings and I want to export only text from a string (delimiter in the string is "_").
For example:

string: Prijem_LPLC_MO-234_333333

extract: Prijem_LPLC

My code:

```
Public Function komentar(text_string As String) As String
Dim text() As String
Dim pom As String
text() = Split(text_string, "_")

komentar = ""
For i = LBound(text) To UBound(text) - 1
 If Application.IsText(text(i)) Then
    komentar = komentar & "_" & text(i)
 End If
Next i

End Function
```

But it copies full string with "_" at beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit weird. If we go through it,

At first you are splitting the string

> `text() = Split(text_string, "_")`

So in the array text, for the string **Prijem_LPLC_MO-234_333333**, you will have :

- Prijem
- LPLC
- MO-234
- 333333

Then, for each objects in your array, you test if the object is text :

> `Application.IsText(text(i))`

Which is the case of every object in your array.

Finally, you concatenate komentar with this kind of structure :

"**_ + *object you were testing***"

In your case, it'll be something like this :

> First iteration : komentar = **_Prijem**
>
> Second iteration : komentar = _Prijem**_LPLC**
>
> Third iteration : komentar = _Prijem_LPLC**_MO-234**
>
> Fourth iteration : komentar = _Prijem_LPLC_MO-234**_333333**

Indeed, if you want only the text from this string, without the "_" element, the problem is from this line :

> `komentar = komentar & "_" & text(i)`

where you're not only adding the text, but also the "_"

For your code to work, you just have to change this part.
Consider trying this :

```
komentar = komentar & text(i)
```

Post Scriptum  : Also, just an advice here, I think using *LBound(text)* is maybe too much, while you can use *0*, since you want to go through all your array.

> `For i = 0 To UBound(text) - 1`

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. Then actually, I need to check if there's a numeric character in that substring then not to include that substring in the extract. Or if in a substring are all letters, then to include it in extract.

Comment: For alphabetical condition, you can check the ASCII of each characters in your string or use something like [regular Expressions](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1336/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html). After a tiny google search I found [this](https://techniclee.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/isletter-function-for-vba/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633517/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-letters).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `komentar = ""` add `komentar = text(0)`. Your code copies the first symbol, because in this line you`komentar = komentar & "_" & text(i)` the first time komentar is empty. So the code returns " _Prijem".

Answer (score 0):

You are close.

For eliminating any string with digits, you need to check each character.
With your method of putting together the result string, there will always be an underscore at the start.  (An alternative would have an underscore at the end).  So after you're done, merely remove the first character.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function komentar(text_string As String) As String
Dim text() As String
Dim pom As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

text() = Split(text_string, "_")

komentar = ""
For i = LBound(text) To UBound(text)

'Check each character
 For j = 1 To Len(text(i))
    If Mid(text(i), j, 1) Like "#" Then Exit For
 Next j

'j will pass this test if no characters are digits
 If j > Len(text(i)) Then
    komentar = komentar & "_" & text(i)
 End If
Next i

'Strip off the first "_"
komentar = Mid(komentar, 2)

End Function
```

You could also do this with regular expressions in VBA, but that's a very different solution.