# VBA Code for Multiple if conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I need to categorize my data into different buckets. my worksheet has column V & Column Y (actually a name match & address match respectively) has values that are either "ok" or "check". Column O has IDs, of which some are only numeric and some are alpha numeric.i need to fill my column A based on these 3 columns.

category 1 - Column A to be filled with "Verify name & Address" - logic for this is - If Column A is blank, Column V value = "check", Column Y value = "check" and column O = all alphanumeric IDs (except that starts with CWT) and numeric IDs = 2 & 9612

Category 2 - Column A to be filled with "Verify Address" - logic for this is - If Column A is blank, Column V value = "ok", Column Y value = "check" and column O = all alphanumeric IDs (except that starts with CWT) and numeric IDs = 2 & 9612.

```
Sub Rules()
'
'Autofill based on Rules

Worksheets("ORD_CS").Activate
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count


    With sht
      For i = 8 To LR
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" And Range("V" & i).Value = "check" And Range("Y" & i).Value = "check" And Range("O" & i).Value = "2" And Range("O" & i).Value = "9612" Then
                .Range("D" & i).Value = "Verify Name & Address"
            End If
        Next i
   End With
End Sub
```

I have not completed my code. Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: What the content of O cell look like> And what are "all alphanumeric ids"?

Comment: The column O contains both Alphanumeric & numeric IDs as well. An eg for Alphanumeric ID - UBSXF600

Answer (score 0):

The below should work, I changed your O column to be an OR

Edit: for function

```html
Public Function IsAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
Dim intPos As Integer

For intPos = 1 To Len(strValue)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(strValue, intPos, 1))
        Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
            IsAlpha = True
        Case Else
            IsAlpha = False
            Exit For
    End Select
Next
End Function


With sht
   For i = 8 To LR
     If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" And Range("V" & i).Value = "check" And Range("Y" & i).Value = "check" And Range("O" & i).Value = "2" Or Range("O" & i).Value = "9612" Or IsAlpha(Range("O" & i).Value) = True Then
                .Range("D" & i).Value = "Verify Name & Address"
   Else
    If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" AND .Range("V" & i).Value = "ok" AND .Range("O" & i).Value = "2" Or .Range("O" & i).Value = "9612" Then
     Do Stuff
    End If
      End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: I have alphanumeric values in Column O. how do i include that in my coding ?

Comment: What do you need to do with the alpha numerics? I see you included a sample in a comment above (UBSXF600), are the values consistent? Meaning 5 letters followed by 3 numbers?

Comment: They are not consistent. If there are values = 2, 9612 and alphanumeric values in Column "O" and col V = Check & col Y = check then i need to autofill column A as "Verify name & address"

Comment: To test for numeric, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633517/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-letters

Comment: Error Msg - Compile Error