# Is there an easy way to check if the string starts with letters (any 4 letters)?

Tags: excel, vba, string, letter

is there a way to check if the string begins with any 4 letters. I am looking for something like this:

```
If string like "####*" then
'DO STUFF
end if
```

"#" is for digits, I need the same thing but for letters only.
Can this be done without regEx?

Comment: I don't know any wildcard characters that only match text, and the [documentation doesn't provide any either](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/wildcard-characters-used-in-string-comparisons). Regex is normally considered to be [the easiest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29633694/11936678)

Comment: @Plutian, it's quite possible though =). Nice question as it's actually somewhat strange there is no straightforward letter wildcard.

Comment: @Radas - a late post for the sake of the art and in addition to the question* "Can this be done without RegEx?"*  demonstrating how to use the FilterXML() function as alternative :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a way to do this without using regular expressions.  We can try using regex `Test` along with the pattern `^[A-Z]{4}.*$`:

```
Dim input As String
Dim regex As Object
Set regex = New RegExp

regex.Pattern = "^[A-Z]{4}.*$"
input = "ABCD blah"

If regex.Test(input) Then
    'DO STUFF
End If
```

Comment: The `Like` operator has some tricks on it's sleeves to prevent the use of `RegEx` in this case. Nonetheless, I do also like this solution ++

Comment: Small remark, just noticed (I'm no RegEx expert) but wouldn't you want to use `"^[A-Za-z]{4}"`. Do you mind giving a short explaination of  why `.*$`? I guess this is looking for any non-newline characters untill the end of the string. But why? Will delete the comment later ;)

Comment: `^` Is an anchor, making sure the defined pattern must occur at the start of the string. Wouldn't it?

Comment: FYI - you might be interested my approach using the `FilterXML()` function (besides the valid solution of JvdV) as you mentioned *"I don't know a way to do this without using regular expressions"* :-) @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `Like` almost the same as with RegEx.

"{#}" - doesn't exist in Like operators, but "[A-Z]" absolutely valid

```
if string like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*" then
   'DO STUFF
end if
```

Comment: `If str Like "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*"` Then to account for lower case too :). Nice solution, I added another version too =). ++

Comment: The big question now is whether invoking full regex performs substantially worse than your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> *Can this be done without regEx?*

Yes, there is no specific need for `Regular Expressions` since the `Like` operator is quite capable as some sort of last resort to handle the situation, just like the writer of [this](https://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/) article explains. Also, `RegEx` is sort of slow on a larger database. Nonetheless, `RegEX` is a great tool to use!

The solution provided by [@AlexandruHapco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59453552/9758194) would tell you if the string starts with 4 capital letters. But to account for lower OR upper, you can extend this logic:

```
If str Like "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*" Then
```

However, to shorten this a bit we can use [`[!charlist]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/wildcard-characters-used-in-string-comparisons) to tell the operator we are looking for something that is NOT in the provided range. In other words, we could use:

```
If str Like "[!0-9][!0-9][!0-9][!0-9]*" Then
```

This last solution won't work when your string has any other characters than alphanumeric ones.

Comment: "[!0-9][!0-9][!0-9][!0-9]*" won't really suit to check "4 letters", any string with no numbers will match it e.g. "----"

Comment: @AlexandruHapco, very true. If there are "special" characters, then it won't work but then you need the solution above it.

Comment: I think I also `Like` this solution +1.

Comment: Interesting, however I find the line somewhat blurry as to whether what you feed the `like` operator here would be called a regular expression. It's doesn't use the VBA `RegExp` operator as Tim does, but it certainly fits the criteria of a regular expression.

Comment: @Plutian, I agree a 100%, however these are what MS calls a "charlist in a pattern". It's build-in and probably has seen it's creators draw from RegEx patterns since they are so alike. One huge difference though is the `*` which in `Like` is used for any amount of characters. In `RegEx` it's used to check for zero or more matches of the pattern defined before it.

Comment: For the sake of the art and in addition to the question* "Can this be done without RegEx?"* I demonstrate how to use the `FilterXML()` function as alternative :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Approach using the `FilterXML` function**

The WorksheetFunction `FilterXML()` has been added in ►Excel 2013 and allows to specify any **XPath** search string for a given XML document, which hasn't to be a locally saved file (needing `WebService()` function), but can be a string within *well formed* opening and closing nodes, i.e. our test string with some easy node additions (partly comparable to a html structure).

**Example call**

```
Sub TextXML()
Dim myString As String
myString = "ABCD blah"
If check(myString) Then
   'DO STUFF
   Debug.Print "okay"
Else
   Debug.Print "oh no"
End If
End Sub
```

**Help function**

```
Function check(ByVal teststring As String) As Boolean
    Const s As String = Chr(185)  ' unusual character, e.g. Chr(185): "¹"
    On Error GoTo oops
    If Len(WorksheetFunction.FilterXML("<all><i>" & teststring & "</i></all>", "//i[substring(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','" & _
       String(26, s) & "'),1,4)='" & String(4, s) & "']")) > 0 Then check = True
    Exit Function
oops:
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

**tl;tr - how to use VBA in Excel versions before 2013**

For the sake of the art the classic way to use XPath via XMLDOM methods:

**Example call**

```
Sub TextXML2()
Dim myString As String
myString = "ABCD blah"

If check2(myString) Then
   'DO STUFF
   Debug.Print "okay"
Else
   Debug.Print "oh no"
End If
End Sub
```

**Help functions**

```
Function check2(ByVal teststring As String) As Boolean
' Purpose: check if first 4 characters of a test string are upper case letters A-Z
  ' [0] late bind XML document
    Dim xDoc As Object
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  ' [1] form XML string by adding opening and closing node names ("tags")
    teststring = "<all><i>" & teststring & "</i></all>"
  ' [2] load XML
    If xDoc.LoadXML(teststring) Then
      ' [3a] list matching item(s) via XPath
        Dim myNodeList As Object
        Set myNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes(XPath())
            'Debug.Print teststring, " found: " & myNodeList.Length
      ' [3b] return true if the item matches, i.e. the list length is greater than zero
        If myNodeList.Length > 0 Then check2 = True
    End If

End Function

Function XPath() As String
' Purpose: create XPath string to get nodes where the first 4 characters are upper case letters A-Z
' Result: //i[substring(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹¹'),1,4)="¹¹¹¹"]
  ' get UPPER case alphabet
    Const ABC     As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  ' define replacement string consisting of an unusual character repeated 26 times
    Const UNUSUAL As String = "¹"       ' << replace by your preferenced character
    Dim replacement As String: replacement = String(Len(ABC), UNUSUAL)
    'return XPath string
    XPath = "//i[substring(translate(.,'" & ABC & "','" & replacement & "'),1,4)=""" & String(4, UNUSUAL) & """]"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To test a few characters -- the first 4 letters in this case -- you can always do the following:

```
If Not (Mid(string, 1, 1) Like "#" And Mid(string, 2, 1) Like "#" _ 
    And Mid(string, 3, 1) Like "#" And Mid(string, 4, 1) Like "#") Then  
    ' DO STUFF
End If
```

It's a bit more to type then when using the Like operator, but so what? Also, you can use `Select Case` in a loop...
Another option is to use `IsNumeric(Mid(string, i, 1))` instead of  `Mid(string, i, 1) Like "#"`, etc.

Granted, this approach is still quite practical with 4 characters, but is not as flexible and very much not scalable like RegEx is.

Comment: *"It's a bit more to type then when using the Like operator"*. You have left me confused, since you are using the `Like` operator yourself. Why not use it to it's full potential? You'r typing more than the other answers  =).

Comment: @JvdV Indeed, like I said in the answer, it's more typing. But, say, you are interested in the 3rd and the 27th characters only. This solution is easily adaptable (and twice shorter now) to this or any other "few characters" need. How would "the full potential" solution work in this case, I wonder.